# How to track loop values after Parallelizing

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have a nested for loop which takes 30 seconds to run and I'm looking to parallelize it based on the number of cores on my machine.

**Original loop:**

```
var currentCap = model.LoanCap;
var currentRlRate = model.RlRate;
var maxRateObj = new Dictionary<string, double>();
var maxRateOuterLoopCount = 0;
var maxRateInnerLoopCount = 0;

for (var i = currentRlRate + rlRateStep; i <= maxRlRate; i += rlRateStep)
{
    maxRateOuterLoopCount++;
    var tempFyy = currentFyy;
    var tempIrr = currentIrr;
    var lowestCapSoFar = currentCap;
    var startingCap = maxRateObj.ContainsKey(capKey) ? maxRateObj[capKey] : currentCap;
    for (var j = startingCap - capStep; j >= minCap; j -= capStep)
    {
        maxRateInnerLoopCount++;
        tempModel = new ApplicationModel(model);
        var tempIrrAndFyy = GetIrrAndFyyTuple(tempModel, i, j, precision);
        var updatedIrr = tempIrrAndFyy.Item1;
        var updatedFyy = tempIrrAndFyy.Item2;

        // stop decrementing cap because we got a good-enough IRR to save this pair
        if (Math.Abs(currentIrr - updatedIrr) >= irrDiffPrecision || updatedFyy < minFyy)
        {
            var endingCap = j + capStep; // go back one step since we just stepped out of bounds
            maxRateObj = new Dictionary<string, double>
            {
                {rlRateKey, i },
                {capKey, endingCap }
            };
            // set vars so the outer loop can check if we are still operating within constraints
            lowestCapSoFar = endingCap;
            tempIrr = updatedIrr;
            tempFyy = updatedFyy;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Break out of the outerloop if the cap gets too low
    if (lowestCapSoFar <= minCap) { break; }
    // ... or if Fyy gets too low (when credit policy is enforced)
    if (enforceFyyPolicy && tempFyy < minFyy) { break; }
    // ... or if Irr gets too low (when credit policy is enforced)
    if (enforceIrrPolicy && Math.Abs(tempIrr - targetIrr) > irrDiffPrecision) { break; }
}
```

Now when I move this loop into the body of `Parallel.For()`, I lose the context which I previously had for the variable `i`... How can I get that functionality back since I need it for my `maxRateObj`?

```
var degreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;
var result = Parallel.For(0, degreeOfParallelism, x =>
{
    var tempFyy = currentFyy;
    var tempIrr = currentIrr;
    var lowestCapSoFar = currentCap;
    var startingCap = maxRateObj.ContainsKey(capKey) ? maxRateObj[capKey] : currentCap;
    for (var j = startingCap - capStep; j >= minCap; j -= capStep)
    {
        tempModel = new ApplicationModel(model);
        var tempIrrAndFyy = GetIrrAndFyyTuple(tempModel, i, j, precision);  // i IS NOT DEFINED HERE!
        var updatedIrr = tempIrrAndFyy.Item1;
        var updatedFyy = tempIrrAndFyy.Item2;

        // stop decrementing cap because we got a good-enough IRR to save this pair
        if (Math.Abs(currentIrr - updatedIrr) >= irrDiffPrecision || updatedFyy < minFyy)
        {
            var endingCap = j + capStep; // go back one step since we just stepped out of bounds
            maxRateObj = new Dictionary<string, double>
            {
                {rlRateKey, i }, // i IS NOT DEFINED HERE!
                {capKey, endingCap }
            };
            // set vars so the outer loop can check if we are still operating within constraints
            lowestCapSoFar = endingCap;
            tempIrr = updatedIrr;
            tempFyy = updatedFyy;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Break out of the outerloop if the cap gets too low
    if (lowestCapSoFar <= minCap) { return; }
    // ... or if Fyy gets too low (when credit policy is enforced)
    if (enforceFyyPolicy && tempFyy < minFyy) { return; }
    // ... or if Irr gets too low (when credit policy is enforced)
    if (enforceIrrPolicy && Math.Abs(tempIrr - targetIrr) > irrDiffPrecision) { return; }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do `degreeOfParallelism` number of parallel iterations. Perform the same number of iterations in your parallel loop as you were doing previously, but spread them over your processors by using `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`.

It looks to me like it's a matter of performing a parallel loop from 0 to `numSteps` (calculated below), setting the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of your loop, and reconstituting `i` from the value of `x` in the loop body. Something like...

```
var start = (currentRlRate + rlRateStep);
var end = maxRlRate;
var numSteps = (end - start) / rlRateStep;
Parallel.For(0, 
    numSteps, 
    new ParallelOptions { 
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = degreeOfParallelism 
    }, 
    x => {
        var i = (x * rlRateStep) + start;
        //lean on i
    });
```

Comment: `numSteps` must be an `int` or `long`, so is it best to Round up to the nearest whole number?

Comment: There was no indication of type in your code, but yes, I imagine some converting to `int` might be necessary.

Comment: ok cool. And what exactly is `x` here? Does it just keep track of the count of iterations?

Comment: Effectively yes... `for(var x=0;x<end;++x){}` is the "linear" equivalent to `Parallel.For(0,end,parallelOptions,x=>{})`. The body of both loops will see the same values of `x` (but not necessarily in the same order, due to parallel execution)

Comment: So, in the example above, the loop body will run with a value of x ranging from 0 (incl) to numSteps (excl).